# How to Show layered navigation on Home page?

Tags: magento

when i will click on home link  on topmenu,
I want to show like Navigation: Home on my home page But i donot know how to do this because home is not a category in admin but i want to show in layered navigation.
if anyone knows this then please help me out.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello add below code into your Home cms page in Layout Update XML

for 2 columns with right bar

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

for 2 columns with left bar

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: my home cms page is of 3 columns.so can you tell me what i will do for 3 columns..

Comment: Add above code in your layout. if you want on left then use reference name left . for right use  reference name right

Comment: I think this is not just enough to display the `layered navigation`. is it?